# React redux Firestore cannot add Document to non existent Collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I try to create a Document in Firestore and want to add it to a Collection which does not exist yet.

```
const firestore = useFirestore();
let data = { date: Date.now(), state: HISTORY_ITEM_NOT_PAID, drinks: addedDrinks };
// addedDrinks = [{active: true, count: 1, id: "asdf"}]
let drinks = await firestore.add(`users/${auth.uid}/drinks`, data)
    .then(result => {
        console.log("Success", result);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error", error);
    });
```

The Collection users and the Subdocument with the User Uid exists. Now I want to add a Document into the Collection "drinks".
But this is not possible if the Collection does not exist.
How can I create a Collection and add a Document to it?

**UPDATE:**

The above code was updated. When I try to add the document to the collection, I get into the successful part of the code. The `console.log` shows me a DocumentReference with a path to the document etc. When I try to navigate to the part in the firestore console I get an error, that the document does not exist.
Also the collection "drinks" is not getting added.

**UPDATE 2**

```
if((await firestore.get(drinks.path)).exists){
    console.log(`${drinks.path} exists`)
} else {
    console.log(`${drinks.path} does not exists`)
}
```

In the above code I wait for the firestore action to finish and store the result in the variable `drinks`. When I try to fetch the document and check for the existens like in the code shown here, it returns `false`. For some reason, when I refresh the page and try it again it works. Do you have any explanation for this?

Comment: There is no need to create a collection in order to create a document.  In fact, there is no way to create a collection alone without also creating a document in it.  There is something else wrong here, and you should do some error checking or other debugging to figure out what's going wrong.  Please edit the question to show your debugging details, especially the result of `add` which you are not checking. Also check that `auth.uid` contains the value you expect.

Comment: So I have checked. The auth.uid is definetly correct. When I add data to an not existing collection, it takes a few tries before one document gets added. Altough I get the success result every time. I use react-redux-firebase to add data to the Firestore. I don't really know what I am doing wrong. There is no need to add more code above, because thats literally what I am doing

Comment: You still haven't shown any code that checks for errors, or the logging you've done to show what's happening before or after the call. There need to be enough information in the question that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: So what is the error?  What exactly are you doing that we can also do and reproduce the problem?  We can't see what you see in the console, we can't see the value of `auth.uid`, so we have no way of confirming any of what you've shared so far.

Comment: `auth.uid` is the Uid of the logged in user, it is definetly set to a value. There is no error, thats my problem, if there was one I would have a starting point but I don't. In my console I see, that the Document is created altough it is not. It is not appearing in my firestore after refreshing the page whatsover.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @Doug Stevenson:

> There is no need to create a collection in order to create a document. In fact, there is no way to create a collection alone without also creating a document in it. There is something else wrong here, and you should do some error checking or other debugging to figure out what's going wrong. Please edit the question to show your debugging details, especially the result of `add` which you are not checking. Also check that `auth.uid` contains the value you expect.

---

Reference

- [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)